# Better performing access to multiple indices in Julia arrays holding a condition

Tags: julia

I read somewhere that looping rather than vectorized operations perform better in Julia. Yet I am stuck with an R-like indexing of arrays/dataframes, which I do not know how it is implemented. I also do not see a direct solution for improving it when my arrays are large.

```
arr = zeros(Int64, (10,2))
out = zeros(Int64, (10,2))
arr[:,1] = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
arr[:,2] = [2 3 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 5]
for i in 1:10
    for j in 1:2
        x[i,j]=sum(arr[arr[:,2] .== i, j])
    end
end
x
```

This is just a demonstration of the array, the arr is usually an array with almost ~100K rows.
This works perfectly fine, but I wanted to know if there is a better performing way that I can do this.

Comment: Can you edit it for the full example? For example, parenthesis are missing and you didn't show what size array you're using. The size of the array can matter a lot for what kind of code is optimal.

Comment: I edited the code, In general the `arr` has two columns, but the number of rows can go crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my computer the following is >100x as fast as Chris' `view` version:

```
x = zeros(Int, 10, 2)
for j in 1:size(arr, 2), i in 1:size(arr, 1)
    x[arr[i, 2], j] += arr[i, j]
end
```

**Edit:** So I wrapped everything in functions and timed it using `BenchmarkTools`:

Original function:

```
function accum0(arr)
    x = similar(arr)
    for i in 1:size(arr, 1)
        for j in 1:size(arr, 2)
            x[i,j]=sum(arr[arr[:,2] .== i, j])
        end
    end
    return x
end
```

Chris' version:

```
function accum1(arr)
    x = similar(arr)
    for j in 1:size(arr, 2), i in 1:size(arr, 1)
        x[i,j]=sum(view(arr,view(arr,:,2) .== i, j))
    end
    return x
end
```

My version:

```
function accum(a)
    x = zeros(eltype(a), size(a))
    for j in 1:size(a, 2), i in 1:size(a, 1)
        x[a[i, 2], j] += a[i, j]
    end
    return x
end
```

Here are the timings with a much larger matrix:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools
julia> const A = hcat(collect(1:2*10^4), rand(1:1000, 2*10^4));
```

Some warming up, and then:

```
julia> @benchmark accum0(A)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  samples:          2
  evals/sample:     1
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%
  memory estimate:  6.26 gb
  allocs estimate:  1080002
  minimum time:     3.64 s (14.60% GC)
  median time:      3.83 s (17.94% GC)
  mean time:        3.83 s (17.94% GC)
  maximum time:     4.02 s (20.97% GC)

julia> @benchmark accum1(A)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  samples:          2
  evals/sample:     1
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%
  memory estimate:  308.98 mb
  allocs estimate:  1005068
  minimum time:     2.69 s (3.81% GC)
  median time:      2.74 s (4.37% GC)
  mean time:        2.74 s (4.37% GC)
  maximum time:     2.79 s (4.90% GC)

julia> @benchmark accum(A)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%
  memory estimate:  312.61 kb
  allocs estimate:  3
  minimum time:     75.60 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      169.22 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        210.90 μs (21.65% GC)
  maximum time:     108.19 ms (99.75% GC)
```

As you can see, the difference is rather dramatic (more than four orders of magnitude). There is little gain to using `view`, there are still lots of allocation. For slightly bigger matrices, neither `accum0` nor `accum1` returns at all within reasonable time.

Comment: Wow, I'm shocked that views have that much overhead. Yes, full devectorization will always be best, but I was hoping that views in this case would get you close enough. I'm surprised that's not the case.

Comment: Not sure if `view` is the problem. Even if `view` were to have zero overhead, you are still allocating every time you do `view(arr,:,2) .== i`. And it is a length `N` vector that is allocated `N` times, so it grows as `N^2`.

Comment: ahh, there it is. I didn't catch that (I wrote the solution rather quickly). So yeah, this is one way to show why devectorized solutions tend to do better. Nice job!

Comment: I am gradually discovering that 'pass through each vector only once' (or a few times) is a really useful general principle. It's a totally new way of thinking for me, though :)

Answer (score 2):

Julia is column-major, so you want to loop down columns, not across rows.

```
arr = zeros(Int64, (10,2))
out = similar(arr)
x   = similar(arr)
arr[:,1] = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
arr[:,2] = [2 3 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 5]
for j in 1:2, i in 1:10
    x[i,j]=sum(arr[arr[:,2] .== i, j])
end
x
```

Notice that you stay in the same column each inner iteration, that's more performant (check the [performance tips](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/performance-tips/)).

Lastly, note that `arr[:,2]` creates a copy of the 2nd column each time that is done. It would be better to make a "view", i.e. a type which doesn't copy the array, just makes a shell type which looks like a vector, but is still pointing to the same values as `arr`. This is done with `view(arr,:,2)`. So you can do

```
arr = zeros(Int64, (10,2))
out = similar(arr)
x   = similar(arr)
arr[:,1] = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
arr[:,2] = [2 3 2 3 4 4 5 6 7 5]
for j in 1:2, i in 1:10
    x[i,j]=sum(view(arr,view(arr,:,2) .== i, j))
end
x
```

This will only be faster when the matrices are larger.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful Chris